# Is the term “in persons’ grammatically correct

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

I heard the following line from the Rick and Morty TV series:

> Forgive me for doing this in notes; I'm not strong enough to do it in persons.

Is it grammatically correct to use in persons instead of in person? Why is there an s at the end?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because without the original source and fuller context, it's difficult to know or be sure that the OP correctly transcribed the quotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing something "in person" is a well known idiom, meaning [to do something physically present, as opposed to by remote communication or through an intermediary.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-person)

There is no equivalent "in persons", even if there is more than one person doing it.

> The two of us went to confront the two of them in person.

The example you give may be a misprint or a joke. It's not possible to tell without context.

Comment: Maybe it’s a joke. the speaker is a hive-mind entity controlling a population. But even then, it doesn’t mean that it can be used as you’ve explicitly elaborated in the example  that even if if the subject and object are plural, it’s an idiom that should be used as is.

Comment: If he is a hive mind inhabiting a population then he is doing things "in persons", meaning "while inside people".